# Triangle area in sphere

Tags: computational-geometry, regions

I have a triangle that intersects with the sphere

[image]

How to count triangle area, which is in sphere?

If you have solution for polygon too, it's awesome.

Comment: Could you please provide some code with the above description. It would also be useful if you could give an example output you'd want to achieve :)

Comment: By basic common sense the intersection of a plane and a sphere is a circle so... couldn't you mathematically solve this by finding the circular intersection and *then* use mathematica for the rest?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's take

```
ball = Ball[];
triangle = Triangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 1}}];
Graphics3D[{ball, triangle}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Then

```
reg = RegionIntersection[ball, triangle];
DiscretizeRegion[reg]
```

[image]

```
RegionDimension[reg]
```

> 2

```
RegionMeasure[reg]
```

> $\frac{1}{4} \left(\pi -2 \sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{7}}\right)\right)$

```
N@%
```

> 0.503427

Similarly for `Polygon`s. The coordinates of neither the `ball`, nor the `triangle` (nor `Polygon`) need to be integers - all work just as well when they are real numbers (the `RegionMeasure` is a real number too).

Answer (score 8):

make a 2d projection to the plane of the triangle and use `RegionIntersection`.

```
triangle = Triangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 3, 1}}];
ball = Ball[{1, 0, 0}, 1];
spherecenter = ball[[1]];
sphererad = ball[[2]];
pts = First@(List @@ triangle);
v1 = Normalize[pts[[2]] - pts[[1]]];
n = Normalize[Cross[v1, pts[[3]] - pts[[1]]]];
v2 = Cross[n, v1];
tri2d = Triangle[{v1, v2}.# & /@ (# - pts[[1]] & /@ pts)];
cc = {v1, v2}.(spherecenter - pts[[1]]);
d = sphererad^2 - ((spherecenter - pts[[1]]).n)^2;
r2d = If[d > 0, Sqrt[d], 0];
Area@RegionIntersection[tri2d, Disk[cc, r2d]]
```

> 1/28 (4 Sqrt[10] + 7 [Pi] + 14 ArcSin[3/7])

( notice I moved the ball center compared to corey979's example to make it a little more interesting )